# My title is showing after the shortcode

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

My code is like following:

```
<?php

    function shortcode_callback() {

        ob_start();

        //my code here

        ob_get_clean();

    }

    add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_callback');

    ?>
```

The above shortcode add to the page but the tile is showing at the bottom of the shortcode:

## My Title

> [shortcode]

There is anything wrong doing I am.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the Page Title is showing after  Shortcode output?

Comment: Shortcodes must `return` their output.

Comment: You're not using output buffers correctly here, but that's a different problem. Avoid output buffers when possible, they're easy to trip up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs to change buffer like this:

```
<?php

    function shortcode_callback() {

        ob_start();

        //my code here

        return ob_get_clean();

    }

    add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_callback');

    ?>
```

Please check after replace ob_get_clean(); in your code with return ob_get_clean(); then it's working fine.

Comment: While this may answer the question it may not be clear _why_ it answers the question. Could you please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/266042/edit) ( using the [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/266042/edit) link below your answer ) and add in an explanation on what you changed from the questions code and why it answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

You Must return output, Follow the following code.

```
function shortcode_callback() {

        $test = 'you text';

        return $test;
    }

add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_callback');
```